# Importing custom coordinate system into ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have custom coordinate system (Korea).

If I want to import it, what should I do?

I'd like to know another way instead of (Define projection -> import -> one by one files). I'd like to know how to import a whole folder in C drive using ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: If you browse to the tool in ArcToolbox, can you right-click its name and choose Batch? Otherwise,  you'd have to use arcpy. If you're using shapefiles only, you could copy/paste one prj file, then just update the name to match the shapefile's.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your question to expand upon the data types/formats, the exact projection details, and what you have tried. Given the large number of different formats, and how CRS metadata is stored, there are a number of potential solutions.

Comment: There used to be a tool *Batch define Coordinate System* but that disappeared a few versions ago, for now find *Define Projection* in the toolbox, right click and select *batch*, locate and drag/drop *all of your feature classes and rasters* you wish to define into the box, find the top row and define the custom CRS then right click on the CRS and hit 'fill' to populate all the rows the same. Be careful when defining in batch, it will overwrite any existing CRS but not change the coordinates, if you have a mixture of different CRS data then Project is the tool you want.